# Looping through labels of a div

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a div tag  with an id which is set to run at server so can be accessed from the code behind in asp.net.

```
<div id="myTst" runat="server">
    <asp:label id="lbl1" Text="Hello" runat="server" />
    <asp:label id="lbl2" Text="World" runat="server" />
</div>
```

I am trying to load the control and then loop through it, finding all of the label child controls of the div and then reading their text values. I wondered if anyone knew of a good approach to doing this.

In the code behind I am doing something like...

```
Dim myPlaceHolder As ContentPlaceHolder = DirectCast(Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"), ContentPlaceHolder)
    Dim cntrlDiv As HtmlControl = DirectCast(myPlaceHolder.FindControl("myTst"), HtmlControl)
```

Comment: You used runat"server" instead of runat="server"

Comment: Why do you have to search the `div` through the master? Can't you access it directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need something like this.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a recursive list of controls inside the current control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control">The control.</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function RecursiveControlList(ByVal control As Control) As Generic.List(Of Control)
        Dim lst As New Generic.List(Of Control)
        Return DoRecursiveControlList(control, lst)
    End Function

    Private Function DoRecursiveControlList(ByVal control As Control, ByVal currentList As Generic.List(Of Control)) As Generic.List(Of Control)
        If Not control Is Nothing Then
            For Each child As Control In control.Controls()
                currentList.Add(child)
                DoRecursiveControlList(child, currentList)
            Next
        End If

        Return currentList
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `div` is on top of the (`Content`-)`Page` you don't need to search it via `FindControl` from the master. You can access it directly. Then you can use `Controls.OfType` to get all labels in the div:

```
Dim allLabels = Me.myTst.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
For Each label As Label In allLabels 
   Dim text = label.Text
Next
```

`Enumerable.OfType` is a handy method that filters by type. It does *not* search recursively. But that's not be necessary anyway since the labels are not nested in different `NamingContainer`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a asp:Panel or do it like you have done it which is making the div runat server. 
In the code behind you can ask the controls(children) of an element. 
You can use the controls property

```
div.controls
```

You could loop through these and then you have to check the label type like this

```
    //Loop through each Control in ControlCollection.
    foreach (Control control in base.Controls)
    {
        if (control is Label)
        {
            //Do your thing here
            var a = control.Text;
        }
    }
```

for more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.100).aspx

EDIT : I have tried writing it for you in vb.net

```
' Loop through each Control in ControlCollection.
For Each control As Control In MyBase.Controls
    If TypeOf control Is Label Then
        'Do your thing here
        Dim a As String
        a = control.Text
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop through each control in the div and check whether it is a label and if it is a label then get its test into a string variable, you can use the following code

```
   Dim s As String = ""
    Dim l As Label
    For Each ctrl As Control In myTst.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is Label Then
            l = DirectCast(ctrl, Label)
            s &= l.Text '<--- output will be Helloworld in this situation
        End If
    Next
```